# Deploying Django with Mezzanine on FastCGI

Tags: django, deployment, fastcgi, fabric, mezzanine

I'm in the middle of trying to deploy a Django project on Subsys.no, Who uses FastCGI. I have never deployed a project before and have been trying for 3 days straight.

I have made a virtualenv on the server and installed all the packages I need. 
I have uploaded (FTP) the project I have onto the server (in the correct place)
I have tired using Fabrics "fab all" command on the server and locally. The server gave this response:

```
--
all
---

-------
install
-------

$ cat /etc/default/locale ->


Fatal error: Low level socket error connecting to host subsys.no on port 22: Connection refused (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
Connection refused

Aborting.
```

The local gave the same answer but with one twist:

```
Fatal error: Timed out trying to connect to subsys.no (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
timed out
```

I'm not sure if the error lie here or [here](http://tryggoversikt.no) on the site. It gives out alot that I dont understand.

All help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: The error on the site says that there is no `mezzanine` module installed (may be your application tries to use system-level python), check it first.

Comment: When I check with
    `which python`
I'm told that I'm using the right one

Comment: Do you see `mezzanine` in `pip freeze` output?

Comment: The `pip freeze ` gave this output.

`Warning: cannot find svn location for flup==1.0.3.dev-20110405
Django==1.5.1
Fabric==1.6.0
Mezzanine==1.4.5
Pillow==2.0.0
bleach==1.2.1
filebrowser-safe==0.2.26
## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:
flup==1.0.3.dev-20110405
grappelli-safe==0.2.21
html5lib==0.95
paramiko==1.10.1
pycrypto==2.6
pytz==2013b
wsgiref==0.1.2`